# What is the size of the Ethereum blockchain for full and light nodes?

Tags: blockchain, mining, blocks

> What is the size of the Ethereum blockchain for full and light nodes?

What is the size of the Ethereum blockchain, and where can I look it up?

Furthermore, does the size depend on the particular client, e.g., geth?

How much does the size increase over time? Is the growth rate fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer here: https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast

Also, I'm running two nodes on two different machines with

```
parity --tracing on (70 GB)
```

in one case and

```
parity --tracing on --pruning archive (556GB)
```

in the other.  Sizes are listed next to the command line. Not sure if size depends on client, but I would guess not to a big extent.

While the chart above looks sort of like the rate of growth is fixed, I don't think it is (at least not for the archive mode). At the time of the Byzantium fork my archive node was about 330 GB (that's after nearly two and a half years). Since then, it's added 220GB. Clearly not a fixed rate of growth.